# vue.js unit testing with Jest : Should I mock the HTLL5 audio element?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Testing an AudioPlayer vue component, which contains the HTML5  element , I wonder how to write my specs with Jest .

template

```
    <audio id="player" ref="player" @ended="ended" @canplay="canPlay" :src="file"></audio>
```

If I use the following wrapper

```
const wrapper = mount(AudioPlayer, {
      propsData: {
        autoPlay: false,
        file,
        ended,
        canPlay
      }
    });
```

How should I set the file property ? ( I want to pass an audio file from src/assets/audio/mysong.mp3 )

If I use shallowMount instead, should I mock the audio element ? which way ... as the audio element handles play(), pause(), mute() ... I am a little bit lost and I cannot find any post related to testing such component...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty sound file to initialize the component, you can inline it using base64 data uri

```js
const file = 'data:audio/wave;base64,UklGRjIAAABXQVZFZm10IBIAAAABAAEAQB8AAEAfAAABAAgAAABmYWN0BAAAAAAAAABkYXRhAAAAAA==';
const wrapper = mount(AudioPlayer, {
      propsData: {
        autoPlay: false,
        file,
        ended,
        canPlay
      }
    });
```

see also:
[Silent sound data uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150729/silent-sound-data-uri)

Answer (score 0):

i check how the Heading.vue parent component is setting up the file property, it's not a string or a file it's an Object from a computed method :

```
 data() {
  return {
    file: "ultimo_desejo",
   ....

computed: {
<audioplayer id="audioplayer" v-if="listening" v-show="showAudioPlayer" :autoPlay="autoPlay" :file="audioFile" :canPlay="audioReady" :ended="switchAudioPlayer" @ended="switchAudioPlayer"></audioplayer>
....
```

and in the AudioPlayer child component

```
props: {
    file: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
```

So I can set the props in my AudioPlayer.spec file

```
const file = require("@/assets/audio/ultimo_desejo.mp3");

const wrapper = mount(AudioPlayer, {
  propsData: {
    autoPlay: false,
    file: file,
    ended,
    canPlay
  }
});
```